# How to ensure an account is unique

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I'm developing an account system with spring-boot and mysql and mybatis.

I used an unique index on the table field, and when an new request comes, I used try catch to do with it.

I think it is not good.

```java
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("query/{id}")
    public String query(@PathVariable int id){
        return userService.query(id).toString();
    }
    @RequestMapping("insert")
    public String addUser(){
        User user = new User();
        user.setAccount("aaa");
        user.setPassword("password");
        try {
            userService.insert(user);
        }catch (Exception e){
            if (e.getLocalizedMessage().contains("Duplicate entry")){
//                Duplicate entry index
                user.setId(-1);
            }else{
//                other Exception
                user.setId(-2);
            }
        }
        return user.toString();
    }
}
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `iacc` (`account`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are using Spring-Boot,myBatis you can make additional call to repository to check whether User exists before registering the User

```
@Select("select * from user where account= #{accountVar}")
User findById(@Param("accountVar") String accountName);
```

And if you have user exists with same accountName you should throw Customize Exception and / or Response Message mentioning User already exists or something similar

**Remember to adhere to Spring Boot or rather HTTP based standards for responding from endpoints**

- In case of success you should return 200 OK along with message or
  whatever best suited in your case
- In case of failure/Exception you
  should return 400 Bad Request along with message

Comment: query first and then insert is not atomic, because Servlet is multi-threading.If there are one more concurrent requests .

Comment: where do you use servlet ? can you be more specific?

Comment: Tomcat was embedded in spring-boot.

Comment: here is the stack
com.example.controller.UserController UserController.java addUser
...
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet FrameworkServlet.java doGet
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet HttpServlet.java service
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet FrameworkServlet.java service
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet HttpServlet.java service

Comment: I think you are completely missing on the point of servlet as well as spring boot... as you are using spring boot you will have to use @Restcontroller instead of servlet...can you post the Usercontroller Code(well formatted) in question?

Comment: I'm sorry.I have post UserController.java

Comment: ok, As you are using Spring boot your controller,service is singleton by default
so in order to handle concurrent request you will have to make service layer thread safe by adding transactional support you can add Spring @transactional on service/repository layer ... i would prefer adding transactional to service layer in order to maintain consistent db state that way it will act atomic